# Debugging AUC error in R. A data table is provided. Thanks

Tags: r, auc

I am trying to calculate a an AUC for the following predictions, and outcomes using the AUC function, but I keep getting an error. I am supposed to do this by tomorrow. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

```
structure(list(POD1HemoglobinCut = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("[10,Inf)", "[0,10)"), class = "factor"), pred = c(0.0044102752927413, 
0.00782725095161221, 0.210140717409347, 0.066525545459026, 0.0666137804946143, 
0.0125809431305506, 0.0107560804580978, 0.829245110498723, 0.759165998590355, 
0.0128042545229042, 0.738354081921031, 0.00287448336844446, 0.0448026818172726, 
0.0162243785121634, 0.0687716959646373, 0.0724616690876388, 0.005033110699528, 
0.893314696161109, 0.883299551200163, 0.189696433058773)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

roc <- roc(test, x = test$pred, class = test$POD1HemoglobinCut)
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Error in `rlang::ensym()`:
! Can't convert to a symbol.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: What package are you using? I can't see that with either `AUC::roc` or `pROC::roc`.

Comment: pROC package 
library(pROC)

Comment: `roc <- pROC::roc(test, POD1HemoglobinCut, pred);
plot(roc)`  does the task?

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't work for me. Even with this shortened version, I get the error: Error in is_equal_cpp(class.sorted, pos_class) : 
  argument "pos_class" is missing, with no default